# Bash script beginner questions: Looping, Arrays and character checks

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I'm taking a class that has us programming scripts in bash, and I am very new to bash.

My professor gave us an assignment:
"Write a Bash script, count.sh, which builds a table of counts for the commands under /bin which start with each letter.  For example, if there are 3 commands starting with "a" (alsaumute, arch & awk) while there  may be  2 commands starting with "z" (zcat & zsh).  The first and last lines your script will print would be:
a 3
...
z 2"

So I've been working on this problem and I'm able to set up the loop, but I'm fuzzy as to how I'm supposed to retrieve the bin commands(I'm assuming bin is a file with just a list of commands for bash?) and then perform a character check on the first character?

He told me to use ls and grep as a hint. I looked up ls (list files/directories) and grep search for a specific text, so I assume I use ls to get the bin commands somehow and then perform a grep on them in the loop?

```
declare -a letters=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z')

counter=0
         while [  $counter -lt 26 ]; do
            current=${letters[$counter]}
             echo The counter is $counter
             echo $current
             let counter=counter+1 
         done
```

That's where I am so far, so my guess is I create a a variable array to also hold all the bin commands(using ls right?), and then use that in the loop with grep?

I just want to get some advice that I'm on the right path. I'm very new to linux and I've never dealt with scripts or cmd line type stuff.

[Here's the output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKK0V.png)

Comment: ‘*I'm assuming bin is a file with just a list of commands for bash?*’ You know what they say happens when you assume? That assumption is very wrong.

Comment: try `ls -l /bin/`

Comment: @sherrellbc [Or don't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Your professor is giving you bad advice. Using `ls` and `grep` is not recommended; see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @Biffen, "try `ls -l /bin/`" to see what `/bin/` is all about.

Comment: @sherrellbc Oh, I thought you meant in the script.

Comment: As an aside, you can iterate over array entries without having any index at all. `for current in "${letters[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: BTW, make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before posting questions here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay, that seems like an interesting tool

Comment: @Biffen I figured it was, I just wanted to check, I didn't really understand what it was when searched it. Might as well ask.

Answer (score 4):

If using bash 4.0 or newer, the following is an implementation that uses *only* functionality built into the shell -- no `ls`, no `cut`, no `grep`, no `awk`, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- must be run with bash, 4.0 or newer; NOT /bin/sh.

declare -A counts=( )            # declare an associative array mapping letters to counts
for entry in /bin/*; do          # use a glob to list filenames in /bin
  filename=${entry##*/}          # strip the path off the beginning of each name
  first_char=${filename:0:1}     # take the first character of what's left
  (( counts[$first_char] += 1 )) # and update the associative array's counter
done

# ...then, iterate over the keys in the associative array...
for first_char in "${!counts[@]}"; do
  # ...and print them alongside their associated values (the counts)
  printf '%s %s\n' "$first_char" "${counts[$first_char]}"
done
```

You can also view the associative array this builds with `declare -p counts`; it'll look something like the following (taken from a system where most interesting things are in `/usr/bin` rather than `/bin`, so rather sparse in the below example):

```
declare -A counts=([b]="1" [c]="4" [d]="4" [e]="3" [h]="1" [k]="2" [l]="4" [m]="2" [p]="3" [r]="2" [s]="4" [t]="2" [u]="1" [w]="1" [z]="1" )
```

---

Some notes:

- As a general rule, shell builtins are (much!) faster than launching an external tool to process a single value, but slower than having an external tool process a long list of values. Command substitutions and pipelines both launch subprocesses -- requiring the shell to create new copies of itself in memory, with some of those copies thereafter replacing themselves with instances of an external executable file. This is a substantial amount of overhead, and not something you want to do inside a tight loop.
- `ls`, in particular, was designed and built for human consumption rather than machine parsing of its output. (Since `ls` emits its output in newline-separated form, and filenames on common UNIX systems can contain literal newlines, it's impossible for `ls` to represent all possible filenames in literal form!). Avoid its use in scripts and other scenarios where the goal is something other than human consumption.
- `declare -A` is what makes an array *associative*, meaning that its keys can be arbitrary strings, rather than only positive integers. This is a relatively new feature, and is why the above is only compatible with bash 4.0 or newer.
- `"${array[@]}"` iterates over values for that array, whereas `"${!array[@]}"` iterates over its keys. As you already know, `"${array[$key]}"` can be used to map from a key to the associated value. See [the relevant bash-hackers page for more on arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays), or [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).
- `${entry##*/}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) -- one of the most powerful tools for native string manipulation in bash. This particular one trims everything from the beginning to the last `/` found. `${filename:0:1}` is another, taking one character from the filename starting at position 0.
- `(( ))` creates an [arithmetic context](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith), where native C-style math syntax is available (for integer math only).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, eh? the `declare -A counts` line is example output from `declare -p counts`.

Comment: Thanks this was a good answer, although I'm still trying to digest it a little, but it was very informative than just a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of commands, you can use `compgen -c`. Pipe that to `grep`, to find the commands that start with a letter. To get the counts, you can pipe that output to `awk`, and use the `NF` variable to find the number of commands.

```
declare -a letters=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z')

for current in "${letters[@]}"; do
    echo "$(compgen -c | grep "^$current" | wc -l) $current"
done
```

Comment: `compgen` is not restricted to examining, or required to examine, the contents of `/bin`.

Comment: Indeed. This addresses what the assignment *should* be, as opposed to what the assignment *is*.

Comment: I've made this a community wiki, because I just tested it and it doesn't work. Piping to awk apparently gives an output of 1. I would like to figure out what went wrong

Comment: @RichardHamilton, to explain why that didn't work -- `NF` is number of fields, not number of lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, however when I was looking at the output through the script, the results were separated by a space. That's why I put the delimiter to a space.

Comment: I'm curious how you were reviewing the output from `compgen -c` that showed a delimiter other than a newline, and exactly which shell you were testing with.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I shared a link at TutorialsPoint. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdE1RY0VsSUVsRnc

Comment: @RichardHamilton, ahh -- it's the unquoted `echo` argument that did you in there. The output from `compgen` was string-split on IFS (which, by default, contains newlines) into individual words, each of which was passed to `echo` as a separate argument.

Comment: Why are you using `echo "$(...)"` instead of just `...`?

Comment: Thanks, this answer also helped me when I contrasted it to @Charles Duffy solution, I guess my prof told me to solve it an way that wasn't recommended but It's good to at least see what he meant when he told me to pipe ls into the grep command.

Comment: @chepner, to eat the newline and append the letter to which the count applies. Granted, one could have done that with `awk` too. It *is* community wiki; feel free to improve.

Comment: I misread the statement; didn't see that `$current` was outside the command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

happy lazyness!

```
ls -1 /bin|cut -c1|uniq -c
  1 a
 27 b
 10 c
 ...
```

Comment: `ls -1`is the default when you send `ls` output to a destination other than terminal.

Comment: This will fail if a file name contains a newline. (And whether such a file name *should* contain a newline is irrelevant; the fact is that is *can*.)

Comment: @chepner tell me one linux distribution which uses newline based filenames in /bin .

Comment: @IporSircer Name one that *prohibits* it.

Comment: name one which prohibits to change /bin/bash to /bin/false then all solutions are wrong here.